# If possible, how to use MUI with Qwik framework?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, qwik

I try Qwik framework which looks a lot like Reactjs and uses jsx. And suddenly, I wonder if Reactjs libraries such as MUI can work with Qwik framework.

I tried this code:

```
import { component$ } from "@builder.io/qwik";
import Add from "@mui/icons-material/Add";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";

const AddToCartButton = component$(() => {
  return (
    <IconButton>
      <Add />
    </IconButton>
  );
});

export default AddToCartButton;
```

But I got this this error:

```
QWIK ERROR Code(25): Invalid JSXNode type. It must be either a function or a string. Found: {
  '$$typeof': Symbol(react.memo),
  type: {
    '$$typeof': Symbol(react.forward_ref),
    render: [Function: Component] { displayName: 'AddIcon', muiName: 'SvgIcon' }
  },
  compare: null
} Error: Code(25): Invalid JSXNode type. It must be either a function or a string. Found:
    at logError (E:\qwik\flower\node_modules\@builder.io\qwik\core.cjs:4515:58)
    at logErrorAndStop (E:\qwik\flower\node_modules\@builder.io\qwik\core.cjs:4521:21)
    at qError (E:\qwik\flower\node_modules\@builder.io\qwik\core.cjs:4585:16)
    at Proxy.jsx (E:\qwik\flower\node_modules\@builder.io\qwik\core.cjs:605:23)
    at AddToCartButton_component_4S0nJgnxzBU (/src/addtocartbutton_component_4s0njgnxzbu.js:11:55)
    at useInvoke (E:\qwik\flower\node_modules\@builder.io\qwik\core.cjs:149:30)
    at E:\qwik\flower\node_modules\@builder.io\qwik\core.cjs:4676:32
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async renderSSR (E:\qwik\flower\node_modules\@builder.io\qwik\core.cjs:5280:9)
    at async Proxy.renderToStream (E:\qwik\flower\node_modules\@builder.io\qwik\server.cjs:582:3)
    at async file:///E:/qwik/flower/node_modules/@builder.io/qwik/optimizer.mjs:1776:30
QWIK ERROR Code(25): Invalid JSXNode type. It must be either a function or a string. Found: Error: Code(25): Invalid JSXNode type. It must be either a function or a string. Found:
    at logError (E:\qwik\flower\node_modules\@builder.io\qwik\core.cjs:4515:58)
    at logErrorAndStop (E:\qwik\flower\node_modules\@builder.io\qwik\core.cjs:4521:21)
    at qError (E:\qwik\flower\node_modules\@builder.io\qwik\core.cjs:4585:16)
    at Proxy.jsx (E:\qwik\flower\node_modules\@builder.io\qwik\core.cjs:605:23)
    at AddToCartButton_component_4S0nJgnxzBU (/src/addtocartbutton_component_4s0njgnxzbu.js:11:55)
    at useInvoke (E:\qwik\flower\node_modules\@builder.io\qwik\core.cjs:149:30)
    at E:\qwik\flower\node_modules\@builder.io\qwik\core.cjs:4676:32
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async renderSSR (E:\qwik\flower\node_modules\@builder.io\qwik\core.cjs:5280:9)
    at async Proxy.renderToStream (E:\qwik\flower\node_modules\@builder.io\qwik\server.cjs:582:3)
    at async file:///E:/qwik/flower/node_modules/@builder.io/qwik/optimizer.mjs:1776:30
not rendered
```

Answer (score 9):

[JSX](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html) in this case is the templating language of Qwik but the underlyings are different. It is made similar so you have an easier transition from react as stated in their [docs](https://qwik.builder.io/docs/overview/).

> Qwik is familiar for React developers and can be used to build any type of web site or application.

Qwik offers some adapter for react components you need to install and wrap your components in.

```bash
npm i -D @builder.io/qwik-react
```

And then the usage should look like the [example in their repo](https://github.com/BuilderIO/qwik/blob/main/packages/qwik-react/src/examples/app.tsx).

```js
/** @jsxImportSource react */

import { qwikify$ } from '@builder.io/qwik-react';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';

export const App = qwikify$(() => {
  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="contained">Hola</Button>
    </>
  );
});
```

Comment: Not work. I got new error  https://i.imgur.com/eqJGAOC.png

Comment: @builder.io/qwik-react has the following peer dependencies that need to be installed.

`npm i -D @builder.io/qwik @emotion/react @emotion/server @emotion/styled @types/react @types/react-dom react react-dom`
    
But you should have a warning when installing it, that you need to install the missing peer dependencies.

Comment: Now I have this error https://i.imgur.com/YGDoV9L.png

Answer (score 1):

This thread is a bit older but maybe someone stumbles across it like me.
I had the same issue using a UI-component library and resolved it with the following steps.

- adding `qwikReact` into the vite.config file:

  import { defineConfig } from "vite";
  import { qwikVite } from "@builder.io/qwik/optimizer";
  import { qwikCity } from "@builder.io/qwik-city/vite";
  **import { qwikReact } from "@builder.io/qwik-react";**
  import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

  export default defineConfig(() => {
  return {
  plugins: [qwikCity(), qwikVite(), **qwikReact()**, tsconfigPaths()],
  preview: {
  headers: {
  "Cache-Control": "public, max-age=600",
  },
  },
  };
  });
- qwikify() must be used in a seperate file **only** with `/** @jsxImportSource react */` [as Jonathan pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73505201/20669615).

Be aware that react components will not be treated the same way in Qwik. As stated in the [docs](https://qwik.builder.io/qwikcity/integrations/react/) it should be a migration/testing tool for existing projects where react components should be introduced in "Wide islands".

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who are using Qwik Speak for I18N, the proposed solution will not work as is because Qwik-Speak won't be able to handle the JSX. The solution is to individually wrap the MUI component and then use it normally as so:

```
import { component$ } from "@builder.io/qwik";
import { Link } from "@builder.io/qwik-city";
import { $translate as t, Speak } from "qwik-speak";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import { qwikify$ } from "@builder.io/qwik-react";

export const MUIButton = qwikify$(Button);

export default component$(() => {
  return (
    <Speak assets={["welcome"]}>
      <div>
        <h1>{t("welcome.title@@Welcome")}</h1>
        <MUIButton variant="contained">Do Something</MUIButton>
      </div>
    </Speak>
  );
})
```